# How to store data into Activerecord with a modular Sinatra APP?

Tags: ruby, sinatra-activerecord

I'm new to the Sinatra. I want to use modular style in my application.

I want users input some texts, which would be stored into a model called "Tweet".
However, it keeps showing the error message "NameError - uninitialized constant MiniDemo::Tweet:" when I submit the text.

The config.ru is below:

```
require './app'

run MiniDemo
```

In the app.rb, the code is as follows:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

require_relative './routes/simple.rb'


class MiniDemo < Sinatra::Base

    set :views, __dir__ + '/views'
    set :public_folder, __dir__ + '/public'

    if __FILE__ == $0
        run!
    end
end
```

The simple.rb file in routes folder is as follows:

```
require 'sinatra/base'


class MiniDemo < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
        # "Hello from my Mini Demo.\nNew Test."
        erb :index
    end

    post '/tweet' do
        Tweet.create(content: params[:content])
    end
end
```

The erb file is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <script src='javascripts/twitter.js'></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="/tweet">
                <p>Your Tweet: <input type="text" name="content"></p>
                <input type="submit" id='btn-submit'  value="Tweet">
            </form>

        </body>

    </html>
```

And the tweet model is :

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/base'

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Could you give me some suggestion?
Thanks so much.

Comment: I found the reason. I forgot to require the model Tweet in the app.rb file. What I did is to include the below line in the app.rb file.  ```require_relative './models/tweet.rb'
```

Comment: Hey Sheila, good job on figuring it out. So the question doesn't appear unsolved, you can post your own answer and accept it after 2 days. I was just about to comment that you were missing a require, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks Max, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. I forgot to require the model Tweet in the app.rb file. What I did is to include the below line in the app.rb file. require_relative './models/tweet.rb'